# The Flutter Daemon Failed To Start. Source: Dart(Extension) ~ Help ME

Tags: flutter, dart

The Flutter Daemon Failed To Start. Source:

[image: Dart(Extension)]

Comment: try to restart the ide

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the `--no-sound-null-safety` option in `flutter create` command. You should probably install a Flutter SDK prior *null safety* and create your project.
Run `flutter create -h` for more info.

Comment: No new project is created. It's always the same error.